# group by multiple columns independently and plot distribution

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, visualization

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         user_id          segment                      device         operating_system
0       51958733  small and above                      desktop                     Chrome OS
1       48983182         unfunded                      desktop                     Chrome OS
2       54011662         unfunded                      desktop                     (not set)
3       53932081         unfunded                      desktop                     (not set)
4       51537380         unfunded                      desktop                     Chrome OS
...          ...              ...                          ...                           ...
503657  53898078         unfunded                      desktop                     Macintosh
503658  52169624        long tail                      desktop                     Macintosh
503659  53965505         unfunded                      desktop                     Macintosh
503660  50678194         unfunded                      desktop                     Macintosh
503661  52143912         unfunded                      desktop                     Macintosh
```

I'd like to find a way to efficiently count the distinct number of user for each group (I actually have much more columns/group in my real dataframe) and plot the output in a bar chart (or maybe something else if better suited)

I'm working in a notebook and right now I'm running the following code for each columns in distinct cells:

```
groupby_segment = eda_df.groupby('segment').ahid.nunique()
groupby_segment.plot.bar(x="Segment", y="ahid", rot=70, title="Segment Distribution")
plt.show(block=True);
```

This is not very efficient because I have to create/update each cells of my notebook manually and in addition it's not good for visualisation because each bar chart are separated. I'd like to have them "grouped" into the same visualisation. Also I'd like to have this displayed as a ratio instead of a simple distinct count.

Comment: `'ahid'` is not in the sample data

Comment: please do `print(df.sample(n=40).to_dict('list'))` and paste into the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.subplots()

# Adjust the distance between two graphs.
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.8, top = 2.6)

# Extracting the column names
columns = eda_df.columns
for i in range(1, len(columns)):
    ax = plt.subplot(len(columns),1,i)
    y = eda_df.groupby(columns[i]).count()['user_id']
    ax.bar(y.index,y)
```

You can use "*ax.plot*" or other functions from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index.html) to plot different graphs.

Note - It will create the same graphs for all the columns.